# CSS isn't loading in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a problem with my Django project which does not want to load static files. I tried a lot of solutions proposed here in the forum like:

- settings.py -> setting the STATICFILES_DIRS (I had it from the beginning but was trying different things)
- changing my URL paths in the HTML links tag
- moving everything into one template instead of extending
- adding app name in URLs
- adding CSS to mime
- moving load static to head
  and many more out of which all failed.

Could anyone see what the problem in the code is? Thank you

My project has a structure like this:
my_site

- blog
  -- static/blog
  -- templates/blog
  -- standard Django files
- my_site
  -- standard Django files
- templates
- static
  -- images

[whole folder organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Own.png)

**BLOG:**

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

app_name = "blog"

urlpatterns = [
    path("index", views.index, name="index"),
    path("posts", views.posts_list, name="posts_list"),
    path("posts/<slug:slug>", views.post, name="post")
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

views.py:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html')

def posts_list(request):
    return render(request, "blog/posts_list.html")

def post(request):
    return render(request, "blog/post.html")
```

templates/blog/index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
Yogiri
{% endblock %}

 {% block css_files %}
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/index.css' %}" />
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

static/blog/index.css

```
header {
    background-color: teal;
}
```

**my_site**

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]
```

**templates**

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>

  {% block title %}
  {% endblock %}

  </title>
  {% load static %}
  <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "base_style.css" %}">
  {% block css_files %}
  {% endblock %}


</head>

<body>

<header> 
<a href= " {% url 'blog:index' %} "><img src="{% static "images/logo.png" %}" alt="Yogiri" width="200" height ="100"></a>
Yogiri - Hatha Yoga
</header>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

**static:**

base_style.css

```
body {
    background-color: teal;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the entire folder structure image of your project.

Comment: Your `STATICFILES_DIRS` is `STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]`. I believe it should be `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]`.

Comment: Hi Scratch'N'Purr, I think both are possible, nevertheless I checked  your option and it didn't help unfortunately

Comment: Ram, I have added an image of my structure in the post up at the link whole structure, hope it helps

Comment: What is the path of your css file? You can place it in `/static/css/base_style.css`. But in order to work with this file you have to define `STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')` in your `settings.py` file

Comment: Hi berkeeb, can you please have a look again on my configuration above? I literally have everything like you described. One difference is that the path is static/base_style.css (without css folder) and I reference it as just "base_style.css" -> as its directly in my static folder to which I specified path in the settings.py

Answer (score 0):

This will not work: `<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/index.css' %}" />`

You have set the static path to `[BASE_DIR / "static"]`. This tells Django to look for static files in the `static` directory which is located in **the root directory**.

Place your `blog/index.css` in the root static directory(where you have put the `images` folder).

**EDIT**

Another option will be to include the directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/static')
]
```

Comment: I have blog in my installed_apps in settings, so it should also look for the static folder in my blog directory and it's thanks to this setting: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: @SzymonDrabowicz I have updated the solution. See it now

Comment: Hi Ayush, I have tried changing that but did not help. Even though, this should not be a problem as I have blog in my installed_apps and static/ folder in my STATIC_URL = '/static/' so it actually should look there anyway

Comment: @SzymonDrabowicz That's what I said before the edit. You should put it in the root static folder.

Comment: Why when it's an app level css? I mean, it should look into:  base_dir - static -> thanks to STATICFILES_DIR = ["BASE_DIR / "static"]
AND ALSO INTO app-folder - static -> thanks to STATIC_URL = "/static/" AND having the app installed in INSTALLED_APPS
Is that not correct? 

Anyway, I have a css file with the same message both in root static and in app level static so it's not loading any of them

Comment: @SzymonDrabowicz First read this to clear your concept about `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIR`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#static-files. And then ask questions

Comment: I don't see where you're going with that. By default Django should look into static folders in my installed apps and I have added root static folder to STATICFILES_DIRS so it should also look there. What I stated is correct.

On the other hand , I don't understand why should adding blog/static to staticfiles_dirs help, as Django should look there per default (blog is an installed_app).

Comment: @SzymonDrabowicz are you new to programming?

Comment: I solved the problem, I mistaken rel in html link for ref (confused relation with reference). It did not require any change in the structure as Django is per default loading from static folders in registered applications. Please clear your concept on that to limit frustration on both sides in the future.